# Problem downloading a package and Installing it without internet on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I currently possess 2 machines with the same version of Ubuntu as the title says, one is for the downloading the Packages and one for installing.

After the download has finished I'm transferring the `.deb` packages to the other machine and trying to install it.

I've successfully downloaded the package with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --download-only vim
```

the output from that command is a `.deb` file that can be installed using

```
dpkg -i <package name>
```

But when trying to install with `dpkg` its throwing an error of dependencies.

How its possible if I'm using the `apt-get install --download-only`?

I've already tried a lot of ways using

> Use --download-only:

> `sudo apt-get install --download-only pppoe`
> This will download pppoe and any dependencies you need, and place them in /var/cache/apt/archives. That way a subsequent apt-get install pppoe will be able to complete without any extra downloads.

Another way:

> [Getting .deb package dependencies for an offline Ubuntu computer through Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219828/getting-deb-package-dependencies-for-an-offline-ubuntu-computer-through-windows)

Comment: Are you install to the same machine, where you did the `apt-get`?

Comment: No different machine but same version of ubuntu 18.04.1 sorry forgot to add, i'll edit the question

Comment: vim depends, examples https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/vim

Answer (score 0):

You would have to `apt-get --download-only` in a computer that has the **exact** same packages, because those dependencies will apply. It could work in other cases too though, if they are similar enough.

To be sure you need to run `apt-get` in the target computer:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --print-uris package_name
```

That will list the packages that would be downloaded, if you had internet there. You move the list to the other computer, download the files, and then move them to `/var/cache/apt/archives` in the target computer.

Then you can run the `apt-get` command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install package_name
```

To get the list of files so that you can use it right away, in the target computer you can do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --print-uris package_name | | grep MD5Sum | cut -d"'" -f2 > download.txt
```

You then copy the file *download.txt* to the the computer with internet and you download the packages:

```
$ wget -i download.txt
```

And then move all those _deb_s you just downloaded to */var/cache/apt/archives* in the target computer and you are ready to run the `apt-get install` command.

Comment: I've tried both ways of the articles that I've added and its still looking for dependencies, the systems are the same version and the same packages installed 100%.

Comment: Ok, then show the error message and somebody might be able to help you. The steps above always work, even with different versions, are you sure you followed them? They can look similar to other solutions. Maybe your error message sheds some light. Also add the list of packages you copied from one computer to the other.

Comment: Currently I'm using this example just to install vim to test things out, I've copied the .deb files that came out from the ```install --print uris``` to _/var/cache/apt/archives_ and after I'm trying to install using apt-get install and error comes up: Could not resolve hosts (probably because there's no internet)

Comment: Here's the error: `sudo apt-get install -y vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  ctags vim-doc vim-scripts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vim
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 573 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,152 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,852 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.1`